# How to test forward compatibility for new iOS version?

Tags: ios, xcode, compatibility

What is the best way to run an app (on simulator and real device) on iOS version that is higher then base SDK for this app?

For example. I have an app and base SDK is iOS10.3. I am building and releasing that app using Xcode 8 (which has iOS10.3 SDK). I'm trying to test what my users will see if they upgrade devices to iOS11 and my app hasn't been updated to base SDK for iOS11.

I can download and install iOS11 beta on my device, but I will not be able to run my app from Xcode 8 on that device, correct?

I also can download and install Xcode 9 with iOS11, but that will not be actual test of my old app built with iOS10 SDK running on iOS11, would it?

Comment: You can make your app available via TestFlight and download it on a device with beta of iOS 11. You can read more here : https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: What about debugging? Is there any way to connect it Xcode?

Comment: Unfortunately, no (at least I don't know of a way) . That would be a downside of this approach. If any issues arrise, you'd need to run your app from Xcode 9 and debug them - remember that you can set your deployment target in the `General` tab of your project scheme. So it will still be built against 10.3, though with new tools. Or if you have some crash reporting setup in app (i.e. Crashlytics), then you'd get at least the stack trace in Fabric.

Comment: Thank you. Can you convert that into answer, so I can +1 it?